# Javascript/async function being called twice, returning error on the second turn

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm fairly new to JS/NodeJs, and I've just learned about async/promises. My code below is running a function twice even though it shouldn't. Here is the code and the output, with the problem highlighted:

```
async function itemDetails(req, response) {
    const item_number = parseInt(req.params.listingID, 10);
    const theList = await querying(item_number);
    console.log("LIST " + theList);
    console.log("item_number " + item_number);
        //theList = res.rows[0];
        // define context data
        const contextData = {
            id: theList.id,
            title: 'Listing\'s Details',
            object: theList.object,
            price: theList.price,
            image: theList.image,
            firstavail: theList.firstavail,
            lastavail: theList.lastavail,
            delivery: 'Delivery',
        };
            console.log(contextData);
            return response.render('item_details', contextData);
}

async function querying(code2) {
    const listID = await listIdentification(code2);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
         pool.query('SELECT * FROM listings WHERE id = $1;', [listID], (err, res) => 
            {
               if (err) {
                   throw err;
               } else {
                   const theList = res.rows[0];
                   resolve(theList);
               }
            });
   });
}

async function listIdentification(code) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const listingID = parseInt(code, 10);
            console.log("check " + typeof(listingID) + listingID );
            resolve(listingID);
        } catch (error)
        {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
}
```

> check number36
>
> LIST [object Object]
>
> item_number 36
>
> { id: 36,   title: 'Listing's Details',   object: 'aNYTHIGN',
> price: 2,   image: 'asd.jpg',   firstavail: '2018-01-01',   lastavail:
> '2019-02-02',   delivery: 'Delivery' }
>
> check numberNaN // <--- here is the problem

Why is it running again? It's calling function `listIdentification` again, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: When/how is `itemDetails` called? Please share all relevant code.

Comment: @Jeto itemDetails is called upon a GET request. Not sure if it's relevant, but the call is made by:
app.get('/listing/:listingID', indexControllers.itemDetails);

Comment: If I run this code by calling `itemDetails` manually, I get just one log of the number. Add a `console.trace()` call when that happens to see how/why it's called.

Comment: @Jeto that's because my code is quering from a dB. I did try the console.trace, but it's not showing what is calling that function again :/

Comment: Some formatting was in order.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the issue, in case anyone else ever finds the same problem. As a matter of fact, it was an issue in the line

```
image: theList.image
```

Whenever the database had an invalid URL, I'd get this error. All I had to do was implelment a validation prior to assigning to the array, so I added the following:

```
var pattern = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;

if (!pattern.test(theList.image))
    {
          theList.image="";
    }
```

Now if the URL was invalid, theList.image will have an empty string. And with that change the problem didn't occur anymore. I still don't know why it was being called twice with that error though.

Comment: Assuming `itemDetails` is a serverside function, the error might have caused the client to do another request.